# Add dynamic model to newly created elements via directives in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Following is my [PLNKR CODE](http://plnkr.co/edit/MDTi9fgAVDiYq1EeUYTi?p=preview) which is working fine.

Problem - I need to add dynamic scope to these element so that I can grab the `contact number + type`.

I [google](https://www.google.co.in/?q=add%20dynamic%20model%20to%20directive%20elements%20in%20angularjs) the problem before asking but as I am new to directives in angular I am confused with the results, let me know what else I need to add to grab the result.

Following kind of result I am expecting -

```
contact: [
    {number: 56432452, type: "Cell"},
    {number: 67895644, type: "Work"},
    {number: 78943245, type: "Cell"},
    {number: 66793456, type: "Home"},
    {number: 90546675, type: "Fax"},
];
```

Also, I need to use the same form in **EDIT** mode, let me know what are the extra things that I need to keep in mind while developing this functionality for the edit case.

Following is my `directive` code -

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contact Number<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select class="btn">
            <option>Cell</option>
            <option>Work</option>
            <option>Home</option>
            <option>Fax</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <img src="http://img.informer.com/icons/png/16/3225/3225535.png" class="remCls">
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see currently the `select` and `input` do not contain and `ngModel`. Let me know how do I introduce this to obtain the above mentioned result.

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about, but your plunkr has no directive (not to mention AngularJS code - it's jQuery mostly)...

Comment: @ExpertSystem `I am new to directives` so whatever I can convert to represent my problem I did that...as I mentioned i need to get number + its type(home, work etc) ..I tried adding `ng-model="cntNum[i]"` in the code but it was not working..

Comment: I am telling you, you are not using a directive. And your code looks more like a jQuery app than an Angular one (which are worlds apart - trust me). I suggest you do some more reading and studying tutorials. Once you get the "Angular way" you'll never go back (but you have to understand it first). You'll thank me later :)

Comment: @ExpertSystem I am looking into this https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive right now..let me know if that suffice to my use case..otherwise I greatly appreciate if u share some url to understand the directive world properly :)

Comment: Let me be more clear on this: Understanding the directives is one step further than you are now. First try to understand Angular's basic concepts (custom directives are a somewhat more advanced topic). Try to understand how to construct an Angular app (and not a jQuery one). **Then** try to understand directives.

Comment: The **[Developer Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide)** has a great deal of resources. I definitely recommend the official tutorial and the free courses under "Learning Resources". (And since you seem to be coming from a jQuery background, **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)** is a must-read :) - We've all been there. Don't worry, you'll be up to speed in no time.)

Comment: @ExpertSystem Thx for the expert comment :) I will surely go for a deeper dive in the angular world and once solved in `Angular Way` I will surely paste my answer with a thx for your comments :)

Comment: @ExpertSystem I solved it..thanks to the angular community :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would like to thank [ExpertSystem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2341938/expertsystem) for suggesting me to think in Angular way. Then I would like to thank **Foxandxss** and **medice** from **angular IRC** for making the things right not by code but improving my concept and approach for angular.

This is the [WORKING](http://plnkr.co/edit/kuBHIhqKgL0hbcUQTv4t?p=preview) code, I came up with for the above problem.

Actually I don't need directive and managed things easily without it.

> medice:   directives are fine, but when you set up click events that
>   modify dom, it's gonna break
>
> medice:   angularjs can't bind directives properly

Following is my controller code -

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){

  $scope.cnctnum = [];
  $scope.cncttype = [];

  $scope.types = [
    {name: "Cell", value: 1},
    {name: "Work", value: 2},
    {name: "Home", value: 3},
    {name: "Fax", value: 4}
  ];

  $scope.items = [];
  var i =0;
  $scope.addCnt = function(){
    $scope.items.push(i);
    i++;
  };

  $scope.remCl = function(index){
    $scope.cnctnum.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.cncttype.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
  };

  $scope.getval = function(){
    console.log($scope.cnctnum);
    console.log($scope.cncttype);
  };

});
```

Comment: You didn't need to develop your own directives, but you still used the angular native directives ng-click, ng-repeat, ng-option, etc..

Comment: @JoaoLeal yeah that is why I mentioned ..I was not looking the problem in `Angular` way

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you need but I think you could define your controller as:

```
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
  //Create and array of contacts in your model
  $scope.contacts = [];

  //Add a new contact to the model
  $scope.addContact = function() {
    var contacts = $scope.contacts;
    contacts[contacts.length] = {};
  }

  //Remove a contact from the model based on its index
  $scope.removeContact = function(index) {
    $scope.contacts.splice(index, 1);
  }
});
```

Then on your HTML, you leverage the Angular directives ng-repeat and ng-click:

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button ng-click="addContact()"> Add Contact </button>

  <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
    <label>Contact Number</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="contact.contact">

    <select ng-model="contact.type">
      <option>Cell</option>
      <option>Work</option>
      <option>Home</option>
      <option>Fax</option>
    </select>

    <button ng-click="removeContact($index)"> Remove Contact </button>
  </div> <!-- Close Repeater -->
</body>
```

Here's your PLNKR link with the changes proposed:
http://plnkr.co/edit/VWCdXSnOsY18XoCKxO0t?p=preview